# Button for external link webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I have created a webview in android in which it has external links. If I click that link it redirects to another webview with a fixed header which has button.
This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.app.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/external_webview"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/activity_main_webview">
</WebView>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backtonews"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:textSize="48dp" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/refresh"
            android:textSize="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:singleLine="false">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>    
  </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now my problem is

- My button is getting displayed on both the webview which shouldn't.
- My contents in the second webview is getting overlayed with the bottom and it is not getting separated.

**EDIT**

Please refer [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_1YXYtMNYymR1VnQnJ6SGxFZm8) image

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.app.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/external_webview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/activity_main_webview">
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backtonews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click"
         >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="click2"
        android:singleLine="false">
    </Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I want the button to be displayed only on the external link page. But I'm getting it in both main webview and external link webview page.

Comment: i dont understand ur exactly problem so can u plz make image in paint and upload it

Comment: I have mentioned two webviews: activity_main_webview, external_webview. I want the buttons to be displayed only on external_webview and not in activity_main_webview.

Comment: remove this line android:layout_below="@+id/layout"

Comment: Tried it but it is not working . In fact now the button is overlapping with contents

Comment: dear what u need overlap ot not button ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109918/discussion-between-darshan-kachhadiya-and-reaching-out).